# Jquery Flot chart duplicating y-axis labels

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

Consider the following javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var data = [
        ["May 2016", 2.03939622532918],
        ["Jun 2016", 6.36415136379491],
        ["Jul 2016", 0.233329380914729],
        ["Aug 2016", 6.27892823668946],
        ["Sep 2016", 3.23859124446543],
        ["Oct 2016", 9.45588825113613],
        ["Nov 2016", 2.22466747252894],
        ["Dec 2016", -0.320916905444142],
        ["Jan 2017", -0.353201643503709],
        ["Feb 2017", 1.30472103004291],
        ["Mar 2017", 9.76387249970365], ["Apr 2017", 6.46594529827125]];;
    var zeroline = { lines: { show: true }, data: [["May 2016", 0], ["Apr 2017", 0]] };
    $.plot("#flot-diff-time-cumulative", [data, zeroline], {
        series: {
            bars: { show: false, barWidth: 0.6, align: "center" },
            points: { show: true, radius: 3 },
            lines: { show: true }
        }
        , xaxis: { mode: "categories", tickLength: 0 }
        , yaxis: {/*min:-4, max: 7,*/ tickSize: 0.5 }
    });
});
```

when run in my page, I get the following chart result:

The display is fine, bu I can't figure out why I have two of each y label. Any thoughts would be appreciated. 
[image]
UPDATE: Setting tickSize to 1 solves it, but it doesn't really explain what I did wrong. And if I need a similar chart with half ticks, what do I do then?

Comment: try using tickDecimals instead of tickSize

Comment: What does that do?

Comment: It's repeating because it's rounding the y-axis values to zero decimals. If you set tickDecimals to 1, you will probably see 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, etc. Or you can use a custom label formatter. But I'd still like to know how to tell Flot to format with no decimals, but not repeat, without having to specify the exact ticks.

Comment: I guess one COULD work around it by formatting the data better before passing it off  to the charting method.